# Understanding Querying A Similarity Matrix in Gensim

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, lda

I have an LDA model in gensim that is working and my next step is to calculate similarity statistics for one document against all of the documents in my model. The code I have that does this seems to work well and it presents output, but I'm having trouble understanding what the output actually represents.

The code I have for an example similarity calculation looks like this:

```
from gensim.similarities import MatrixSimilarity

corpus = []
for i in range(len(data_words)):

    corpus.append(dictionary.doc2bow(data_words[i]))

index = MatrixSimilarity(corpus, num_best=10)
query = [(0, 1)]
sims = index[query]
print(sims)
```

and the output looks like this:

```
[(5, 0.13590089976787567), (121, 0.1294933259487152), (208, 0.11649453639984131), (183, 0.09486348927021027), (191, 0.09261536598205566), (86, 0.09157654643058777), (214, 0.09156541526317596), (97, 0.07831937074661255), (210, 0.07211855053901672), (30, 0.06860589236021042)]
```

The thing that confuses me is the variable query and how it interacts with the similarity matrix. What does the tuple represent in terms of the documents in my model? and what is the best way to change the tuple to get the best statistics to show the top 10 most similar documents for a given document?